# Formatting JSON Instagram Conversations for ChatGPT Training

Tags: json, chatgpt-api

I have a collection of Instagram conversations stored in JSON files. I would like to format these conversations in a way that separates my own messages into "side A" and the messages from other participants into "side B." My ultimate goal is to feed this formatted data into ChatGPT to optimize my conversation flow and receive better responses.

Here's an example of the JSON structure for a conversation (with sensitive info removed of course):

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "side B"
    },
    {
      "name": "side A"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "side A",
      "timestamp_ms": 1689053771215,
      "content": "https://www.loom.com/share/",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.loom.com/share/"
      }
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side B",
      "timestamp_ms": 1689019376338,
      "content": "u can send it here",
      "reactions": [
        {
          "reaction": "\u00e2\u009d\u00a4",
          "actor": "side A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side B",
      "timestamp_ms": 1689017227767,
      "content": "yeah"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side A",
      "timestamp_ms": 1688634040591,
      "content": "Awesome! I made a video for you going over how we can get these clients to you.\n\nIs this a good place to send it?\nor do you have an email?"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side B",
      "timestamp_ms": 1688586896721,
      "content": "Yeah you can send them to us.",
      "reactions": [
        {
          "reaction": "\u00f0\u009f\u0094\u00a5",
          "actor": "side A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side A",
      "timestamp_ms": 1688436305970,
      "content": "I recently helped another Sign and Wrap studio generate nearly 200 qualified leads in less than 90 days!\n\n\nI made a personalized video going over some key things that you or your team could apply to generate more appointments asap.\n\nLet me know if I should send it here?"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "side A",
      "timestamp_ms": 1688176789730,
      "content": "Hey,side B I was searching for recommended Sign Shop in your area and found you\n\nWe're receiving a lot of people searching for recommended Sign Companies in your area - would you be able to take on more clients if we sent them to you?"
    }
  ],
  "title": "side B",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_path": "inbox/",
  "magic_words": [
    
  ]
}
```

I would appreciate guidance on how to write code (preferably in Python) to transform the conversations into a format suitable for training with ChatGPT. Specifically, I want to extract my own messages into a separate list ("side A") and the other participants' messages into another list ("side B").

I tried searching online, even using ChatGPT to point me to some resources that could help but I didn't really find anything that was pertaining to this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!